# Socket.io Different Client IDs

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to make a simple multiplayer game using websockets and socket.io.

We've got most features working, and our problem now is finding out who the winning player is.

So the solution we're trying to implement right now is by getting sockets on run time, and when a player dies, they send a message to the server. The server on receiving this message adds a property 'dead' to the socket. So `socket.dead = true` is set when the player dies.

We then check a list of connected sockets (obtained dynamically) to see if there is only one remaining player alive (by checking if socket.dead is defined). One thing we realised is that the socket.ids of connected sockets actually change - and this is prooving to be a problem for us...

The question is where and when does the socket ids change, and how can we detect these changes so that we update our game data?

Thanks

Comment: I don't use node.js but in my websocket games I simply have a user id in every message from the client, this id being given by the server at connection (reused sometimes if same user is detected, and stored in localStorage client side).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't check for the socket id, instead you should authenticate the user each time he connects to Socket.IO (`socket.user = username`).

Then instead of checking for the id of the players that are "alive", you can check for their usernames.

More on handling sessions with Express & Socket.IO here: http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/